# How to correctly create and edit left to right pages in a right to left website?

Tags: theming, 10

I have a website in Hebrew, a language written from right to left (RTL).

Hebrew is used for the administration interface and for the general interface; generally pages are in Hebrew for all users.

I don't have translated nodes, and I also don't want to have any translated node; either a node is in Hebrew or in another language.

My problem is that I need to add some nodes which are in English, written from left to right (LTR) but I am not sure how to do that correctly.

I want that in an English node, both the `H1` and the `article body` will appear LTR, **also while I create or edit it**.

How can I correctly create, edit and combine English nodes in a RTL website, especially when no translations are being used at all?

### What I do for now

For now I use this CSS and JavaScript.

#### CSS

```css
.page-node-type-dp-ltr {
    direction: ltr;
}

.page-node-type-dp-ltr .feed-icon {
    display: none; /* fix feed-icon flowing above text */
}
```

#### JavaScript

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Drupal ltr
// @match        https://example.com/node/1/*

// ==/UserScript==

window.setInterval( ()=>{
    document.querySelector('*').style.direction = "ltr";
}, 1);

window.setInterval( ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.text-align-left').style.direction = "ltr";
}, 1);


window.setInterval( ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable').style.direction = "ltr";
}, 1);
```

It's not backend but it's the only thing I know to do that brings me closest to a backend solution.

Comment: The language module is what informs the rendered html if it is in rtl or not based on the language.

Comment: I am having trouble finding clear documentation for general audience (website builders, SEOers) for this module. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!language!language.module/8.1.x and also https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/language-add.html and also, I am not sure if that's associated https://www.drupal.org/module-categories/multilingual . When you say "based on the language" what do you mean? Based on the `h1`? Based on the `p:first-child`? I would actually prefer to determine this in a content type (node type) configuration, just a thought.

Comment: The html tag has a dir attribute informing the direction of the language on the page, easily targeted by css.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to add a Boolean field to your *article* bundle. For each LTR node you can check this field; then, in your theme, check it and set the direction basing on it.

```
{% set direction = article.field_ltr.value ? 'ltr' : 'rtl' %}
 
<div dir="{{direction}}">
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hello ! What do you mean by "article bundle"? If needed, I could create a new content type (node type) and name it say "LTR pages". My theme is a sub-theme of Olivero; should I add a particular twig file to it and declare it in `theme.libraries.yml`?

Comment: Just a note - I am not a PHP/Drupal programmer, just a Drupal website builder, so I do have a dire need in a passage about where to put this data exactly.

Comment: @jorno, In Drupal 8+, a node *bundle* is a content type. Since the question is about `article body`, the answer assumed that *article* is the content type you are using.